# Causes of Selenium failing when being executed as SYSTEM user from a Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

For some context, I have a Windows Scheduled Task set-up running as the SYSTEM user, which periodically opens a small Console Application which makes use of Selenium and specifically the IE Driver. This works perfectly well for a long period of time, but after a month or two has passed it eventually begins failing every time the scheduled task executes with the error below.

The only solution I have found is to restart the application server, whereby the issue is resolved for another month or two, until it magically reappears.

I have taken a look at other Stack Overflow questions of a similar nature, but their solutions haven't allowed this to be resolved. The questions also don't appear to run Selenium as a Scheduled Task as the SYSTEM user so I feel this is a unique take on the issue?

Does anyone have any advice as to what might be causing this issue to reappear? I am looking to avoid having to restart the server as this has to be scheduled in, resulting in a number of days with my Scheduled Task being in the disabled state causing me to less aware of my application isn't working.

```
Message: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57185/session timed out after 240 seconds.
InnerException: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
StackTrace:    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(String internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory, InternetExplorerOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

Comment: Probably due to other side not having enough slots for another instance. Try this restart the other side to see if things clear up. I'm assuming you're using a Grid.

Comment: This would make sense. As this is running as the SYSTEM user, do you know how I would go about restarting/closing instances for this user? As far as I am aware I'm unable to log in as the SYSTEM user.